# java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01438:

Tags: java, oracle

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column
ORA-06512: at "CARE_SLB.TRG_AFT_I_U_CATEGORY_MASTER", line 21
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'CARE_SLB.TRG_AFT_I_U_CATEGORY_MASTER'
```

Comment: What is the question here? Posting just exception doesn't tell everything about how and why it occurred. Post relevant code and explain what you are doing?

Comment: you might want to update the question to indicate your need. At the moment, this is just a stack trace of an error reported by the Oracle JDBC driver. Do you want to know what the error is? Or something else?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to update a column with a value that is larger than the allowed length.

This happens on line 21 in the trigger `TRG_AFT_I_U_CATEGORY_MASTER`

Steps to solve the problem:

1. Check the code on line 21 which column it is updating
2. Check the column's definition to see what its limits are
3. Check the value you are trying to put into that column and make sure you stay inside the limits

Comment: i want insert records in the table but exception wille thrown like above