# Why does code throw java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01438?

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

I'm inserting data in table through this statement:

```
insert into CATEGORY_MASTER (
  CAT_MAS_ID, 
  DESCRIPTION, ORG_ID, STATUS, MODIFY_EMPID, LANGUAGE_ID, LG_IP_MAC)  
values ( 
  ( SELECT COALESCE(MAX(ct.cat_mas_id), 0)+1 
    FROM category_master ct),
  'fff', 2, 'A', 52,1,'SYSTEM/127.0.0.1/NOTDEFINE')
```

The target table has this trigger:

```
create or replace trigger trg_aft_i_u_category_master
  after insert OR UPDATE of cat_mas_id,status on category_master FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  CURSOR CSTYPE IS
    SELECT CST.SUB_TYPE_ID,CST.TYPE_ID,CST.ORG_ID,CST.STATUS
    FROM COMPLAINT_SUB_TYPE CST
    WHERE CST.ORG_ID=:NEW.ORG_ID AND CST.STATUS='A';
  V_CSTYPE CSTYPE%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  IF CSTYPE%ISOPEN THEN
    CLOSE CSTYPE;
  END IF;
  OPEN CSTYPE;
  LOOP
    FETCH CSTYPE INTO V_CSTYPE;
    EXIT WHEN CSTYPE%NOTFOUND;
    if INSERTING then
      /******** Suspect issue here  *******/
      INSERT INTO CATEGORY_DETAILS(
          CAT_DTL_ID, CAT_MAS_ID, TYPE_ID ,SUB_TYPE_ID,
          ORG_ID,MAP_STATUS,MODIFY_EMPID,LANGUAGE_ID,LG_IP_MAC)
      VALUES (SEQ_CATEGORY_DETAILS.NEXTVAL,:NEW.CAT_MAS_ID, 
          V_CSTYPE.TYPE_ID,V_CSTYPE.SUB_TYPE_ID,:NEW.ORG_ID,'U',
          :NEW.MODIFY_EMPID,:NEW.LANGUAGE_ID,:NEW.LG_IP_MAC);
      /************************************/
    end if;
    if UPDATING then
      if :new.status = 'I' then
        UPDATE CATEGORY_DETAILS CD 
        SET CD.MAP_STATUS= 'U' 
        WHERE CD.CAT_MAS_ID=:NEW.CAT_MAS_ID AND CD.ORG_ID=:NEW.ORG_ID;
      end if;
    end if;
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE CSTYPE;
end trg_aft_i_u_category_master;
```

Comment: same question again but now with some more inormation. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6290873/java-sql-sqlexception-ora-01438

Comment: I think there are two important reasons why people are reluctant to help you. 1) Your formatting is very poor 2) Instead of editing an existing question, you posted a duplicate!

Comment: I don't see how this is related to Java. Should be Oracle and PLSQL. And you might want to put in more effort into formatting the code. It is barely readable in the current state.

Comment: I think the error speaks for itself, http://ora-01438.ora-code.com/ , check the length of your values and compare to the table.  do a DESC CATEGORY_MASTER and post the results

Comment: I helped the newbie out by formatting the code. Please, dear Kiran, use some formatting tool next time. Also, it seems clear by the error code that one of the values is too large. Perhaps you could examine the data to find which value is causing the problem? Maybe the value from the sequence has gotten surprisingly big.

Answer (score 1):

The explanantion for `ORA-01438` is:

> "value larger than specified precision allowed for this column"

So one of your tables (not necessarily MASTER_CATEGORY) has a number column defined with significant digits, and your code is trying to insert a number which is too large.

Given this table ...

```
SQL> create table t42 (col1 number(5,2));

Table created.
SQL>
```

... we can insert a value which fits the declaration:

```
SQL> insert into t42 values (123.45);

1 row created.

SQL>
```

... the database rounds up trailing decimals:

```
SQL> insert into t42 values (12.345);

1 row created.

SQL>
```

... and the database rejects the value when the leading element is too large:

```
SQL> insert into t42 values (1234.5);
insert into t42 values (1234.5)
                        *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column

SQL>
```

This now becomes an issue for you.  You need to describe your tables to see which columns are defined as precise numbers, that is like `NUMBER(3)` or `NUMBER(7,2)`.  Then check the data you are using to estabish which numeric value is too big.  Standard debugging techniques will help.